# strange python dictionary?

Tags: python, api

new to python here. Been trying this for quite a while now; would really appreciate some help.

I thought to try my hand at pulling data from an api, and what i got is a very long dictionary ( or at least i think its an dictionary )

```
response = requests.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/finance_products')
print(response.content)
```

can anyone give me any pointers on how to manipulate the results ?

I can't call the dictionary.

First few characters of it :

`b'[{"platform":"Binance Savings","identifier":"CCOCOS30DAYSS001","supply_rate_percentage":"6.0","borrow_rate_percentage":null,"number_duration":null,"length_duration":null,"start_at":0,"end_at":0,"value_at":0,"redeem_at":0},{"platform":"DDEX Lending","identifier":` etc etc

i'm not sure why there is a b' at the front.

Sorry if this isn't a clear question.

Comment: It’s a JSON string. You need to decode it using `json.loads`.

Comment: @andrasdeak: I flagged this with the wrong duplicate; it seems more concerned with conversion to a JSON object than decoding to a string (Well a little bit of both actually).

Comment: @ChrisMaes the last answer covers that case. Anyway I've added another target.

Comment: @AndrasDeak correct. Great.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
response.json()
```

which decodes it immediatly to a json object. [Documentation here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/response-json-python-requests/)